# why i don't see my files on web app azure FTP?

Tags: wordpress, azure, web-applications, ftp, containers

I have a problem connecting to the FTP of the WordPress container on the AZURE web app.
When I connect, I get one HTML file on /site/wwwroot, but I can't edit or see my files.
In SSH in KUDU, I see the actual files.

What are the problems?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You're likely using the App Service FTP credentials. This will point you to the underlying VM running your App Service and not your container. Since App Service only listens on one port, it's not possible to open both ports 80 and 21 and point them to your container.

Using the Azure CLI, you can open a tunnel using this command and then use your favorite ssh tools.

```
az webapp create-remote-connection --subscription <subscription-id> -g <resource-group-name> -n <app-name> &
```

Using SCP, you can copy a local file to your container:

```
scp -P [port generated from the previous command] "C:\Hello.txt" root@127.0.0.1:/hello.txt
```